# Where statement Hierarchy for Selecting rows

Tags: sql, select, exists, case-when

I have a table with a column called ReportTypeId.  I want to select rows where ReportTypeId = 1, but if no rows exist for this, then I want ReportTypeId = 2.  I am trying to use a WHEN EXISTS, but I cannot figure out how to select more then one column.  I want to write a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT PerformanceReport FROM ReportData
                    WHERE (ReportId = 79 and ReportTypeId = 1))

        THEN (select * from ReferenceData               
                where ReportTypeId = 1)

        ELSE (select * from ReferenceData
                where ReportTypeId = 2)
    END
```

But because I am trying to return more than one column it doesn't work.  Is there a way to create a query that bases it's WHERE statement based on whether the data exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `RecordTypeId` can be ordered**, then you can use the following

```
SELECT PerformanceReport 
FROM ReferenceData
WHERE ReportTypeId = (
      SELECT MIN(ReportTypeId) 
      FROM ReportData 
      WHERE ReportTypeId IN (1, 2)
        AND ReportId = 79
)
```

** by ordered, I mean that the `MIN` aggregate function will return the expected result. For integers this makes sense, however, if your report type ids are text uuids, then `MIN` would still work but won't give you the expected result, because it will return the minimum id in lexical order.

Comment: This works great for my case, but I can see that if ReportTypeId = 2 becomes the priority over 1, but not as import as say 3 (2 > 1 > 3), then I'm guessing I'm out of luck?... Well I guess I can create a temp table that would assign a rank of importance, so actually yes I really like this solution, thanks!

Comment: @Mwspencer . . . I am baffled at how this answer can be accepted when it does not even seem to be selecting from the correct table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think it's the idea more than the hard code that I am accepting. As my actual user case is a bit more complicated than my question, and this answer helped created the most straightforward solution.  I will admit I have not tested for performance though as that is not important to my specific case. All answers gave the correct output, but this one took the least amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ReferenceData
WHERE (
    ReportTypeId = 1 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ReportData WHERE ReportTypeId = 1 AND ReportId = 79)
) OR (
    ReportTypeId = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ReportData WHERE ReportTypeId = 1 AND ReportId = 79)
)
```

You can optimize this with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ReferenceData.* 
FROM ReferenceData JOIN (
    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ReportData WHERE ReportTypeId = 1 AND ReportId = 79) AS state
) isAvailable
WHERE (
    ReportTypeId = 1 AND isAvailable.state = 1
) OR (
    ReportTypeId = 2 AND isAvailable.state = 0
)
```

You can add multiple checks using the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ReferenceData.* 
FROM ReferenceData JOIN (
    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ReportData WHERE ReportTypeId = 1 AND ReportId = 79) AS state
) avail1 JOIN (
    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ReportData WHERE ReportTypeId = 2 AND ReportId = 79) AS state
) avail2 JOIN (
    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ReportData WHERE ReportTypeId = 3 AND ReportId = 79) AS state
) avail3
WHERE (
    ReportTypeId = 1 AND avail1.state = 1
) OR (
    ReportTypeId = 2 AND avail1.state = 0 AND avail2.state = 1
) OR (
    ReportTypeId = 3 AND avail1.state = 0 AND avail2.state = 0 AND avail3.state = 1
) OR (
    ReportTypeId = 4 AND avail1.state = 0 AND avail2.state = 0 AND avail3.state = 0
)
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef6faad61d4affc8518872cb9e790d7a)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT refd.* 
FROM ReferenceData refd
WHERE (refd.ReportType = 1 AND 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM ReportData repd
               WHERE repd.ReportId IN (1, 79)
              )
      ) OR
      (refd.ReportType = 2 AND 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM ReportData repd
               WHERE repd.ReportId NOT IN (1, 79)
              )
      )
```

Comment: This seems like it is a clean solution, but I am not sure why AND is used.  I want to select the report if ReportTypeId =  1 else, I want ReportType = 2, but I don't want both Report Types.  I am also not sure why we are looking for repd.ReportId IN (1, 79) and not just repd.ReportId = 79.